# 4 boxes grid responsive, center content and container right same height of container left

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML structure:

```
<section id="welcome-section">
  <div class="inner-container container">
    <div class="l-sec col-md-8">
      <div class="ravis-title-t-1">
        <div class="title"><span><h1>my title</h1></span></div>
        <div class="sub-title"><h2>mysubtitle</h2></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        description text goes here.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="r-sec col-md-4">
      <div class="buttonsvalue">
        <div class="col-xs-6 buttonboxvalue">
          <a class="" href="#">Very Long Word</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 buttonboxvalue">
          <a class="" href="#">Very Long Word</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 buttonboxvalue">
          <a class="" href="#">Very Long Word</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 buttonboxvalue">
          <a class="" href="#">Very Long Word</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

What I want to do is that inside the "r-sec" div I have 4 boxes that are always fit to the height of the "l-sec" div. Take a look at the attached image please.
Also I want that the content of each box is always verically and horizontally centered inside the box.

[image: Attached image]

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1) you should put your col inside row

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="col-md-8></div>
    <div class="col-md-4></div>
</div>
```

2) for the content of each box is vertically and horizontally centered inside the box. try this

```
.target {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the appropriate Bootstrap `row` declarations. Put a row around `l-sec` and `r-sec` and then a row around each two `buttonboxvalues`.

```
<section id="welcome-section">
  <div class="inner-container container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="l-sec col-md-8">
        <div class="ravis-title-t-1">
          <div class="title"><span><h1>my title</h1></span></div>
          <div class="sub-title"><h2>mysubtitle</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          description text goes here.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="r-sec col-md-4">
        <div class="buttonsvalue">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 buttonboxvalue">
              <a class="" href="#">Very Long Word</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 buttonboxvalue">
              <a class="" href="#">Very Long Word</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 buttonboxvalue">
              <a class="" href="#">Very Long Word</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 buttonboxvalue">
              <a class="" href="#">Very Long Word</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Second step is to use JS to figure out the height of the main content container and then apply that to the secondary container:

```
// Get main container height, apply it to the secondary container
var mainContainerHeight = $('.l-sec').height();
$('.r-sec').css('height', mainContainerHeight);
```

I updated the codepen to show how the example works for different heights on the main content area: 
https://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/QvKQVm

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I cannot set .buttonboxvalue to a fixed height. the height must be variable according to the height of the .l-sec div / 2. I could use calc? Is it cross browser compatible? Any other idea?

Comment: Youre going to have to use JS to do this. There is no way the stylesheet would be able to determine the height of `.l-sec` dynamically and then calculate it. `calc()` wouldn't work in your scenario either.

Comment: @Francesco - I updated the answer to be dynamic. See if this helps you.